# Armadillo in Caffe for pseudo-inverse and transpose

Tags: c++, armadillo, caffe

I need pseudo inverse and transpose function to implement a Layer in caffe. So I am using Armadillo library to do that. But How can I convert Caffe Blobs(2-D) to armadillo Mat and vice-versa ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, I haven''t found a way of conversion between armadillo and caffe blobs.
But I noticed that caffe uses MKL library for CPU computations, which has both of the required functions i.e. pseudo inverse and transpose.
In case, caffe is not configured to use MKL, I can easily implement a function for transpose (which would be better than getting it done using armadillo and then converting data types in O(mn) time).

Answer (score 0):

A Caffe blob is a 4-dimensional matrix, I believe armadillo's `pinv(A)` and `.t()` or `trans(A)` are meant to be used with 2 dimensional matrices of type `mat`.

You could get a vector of a vector of 2-dimensional armadillo matrices to represent a 4-dimensional Caffe blob. You can do so with something like:

```
using namespace arma;
using namespace caffe;

vector<vector<mat>> blob2vvmat (Blob m) {

    vector<vector<mat>> vvm;

    for (int i=0; i<m.shape().at(0); i++) {

        vector<mat> vm;

        for (int j=0; i<m.shape().at(1); i++) {

            mat M (m.shape().at(2), m.shape().at(3));

            for (int k=0; i<m.shape().at(2); i++) {

                for (int l=0; i<m.shape().at(3); i++) {

                     M(k,l) = m.data_at(i, j, k, l);

                }

            }

            vm.push_back(M);

        }

        vvm.push_back(vm);

    }

    return vvm;
}
```

I haven't testing the code, but that should theoretically work, unless you're not looking for a vector of vector of matrices.

If you know your row, column, height and 4d sizes, you can use the symbolic library on MATLAB or octave, or even better: Mathematica to derive and equation to calculate the pseudo-inverse and transpose of a 4d matrix and port it to your program using the `ccode(expr)` function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if I am sure that caffe blob is of dimenstion M*N*1*1. Is there any simpler way in that case ? I mean without loops

Comment: Well, in that case, I'd just remove the loops for i and j and keep m and n. That shouldn't be that bad, especially if you make a function wit hthe loop. That way, you're actually returning a mat instead of a vector<vector<mat>> and you can do whatever armadillo operations you want with it.

Comment: yes that won't be bad for pseudo inverse. But It will not be of any worth in case of transpose, which itself is a O(mn) operation